# Добавление атрибутов по типу data-target="" к ссылкам <a></a> в wp_nav_menu WordPress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Есть полностью кастомная WordPress тема сформированная при помощи underscore.
Есть определенное меню, созданое динамически стандартной функцией вордпресс "wp_nav_menu". Как сделать так чтобы из админки можно было к какой-то определённой ссылке меню добавить атрибут со значением и редактировать его внутри админки? Ещё лучше если можно будет просто вставить кусок html в `<a ...></a>`.

Answer (score 0):

"Из коробки" способа добавить `data-target` не существует. Можно добавить свои метабоксы в админку, с сохранением введённой информации, но потом всё равно фильтровать вывод и вставлять `data-target`.

Проще стандартными средствами добавить класс к элементу меню (включив Настройки экрана->Классы CSS).

Потом отфильтровать вывод:

```
function nav_menu_link_attributes_filter( $atts, $item, $args, $depth ) {
    $key = array_search( 'fff', $item->classes, true );
    if ( false !== $key ) {
        $atts['data-target'] = 'fff';
    }

    return $atts;
}

add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'nav_menu_link_attributes_filter', 10, 4 );
```

Этот код (который может быть помещён в functions.php темы) проверяет, есть ли класс 'fff' у данной ссылки меню, и если есть, добавляет внутрь тега `<a>` `data-target="fff"`. Код будет вызван столько раз, сколько ссылок в меню.